# Ordered Projections: Range

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider two orthogonal projections $P,Q$. Then:
$$P\leq Q\implies\mathcal{R}(P)\subseteq\mathcal{R}(Q)$$

The ordering being induced by:
$$T\geq0:\iff\mathcal{W}(T):=\{\langle T\hat{x},\hat{x}\rangle:\|\hat{x}\|=1\}\geq0$$

Can you give me a hint how to check that lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any orthogonal projection $P$, a vector $x$ is in the range of $P$ iff $\|Px\|=\|x\|$. The condition $P \le Q$ for orthogonal projections is equivalent to $\|Px\|\le \|Qx\|$. Because $\|Qx\|\le \|x\|$ it follows that if $x \in\mathcal{R}(P)$, then $x\in\mathcal{R}(Q)$.

Comment: Do you mind if I extend my question and/or your answer? *(I wanna give like a list of equivalent conditions like range, kernel, norm, numerical range, etc.)* Will come back after lectures, so still some time until then...

Comment: @Freeze_S : If you have a new question, then please post a new one. Fundamentally changing a question can make it look like the person who posted an answer doesn't know what they're doing. I've had you do that before, and it rewarded considerable effort on my part by making it appear that I didn't understand your question at all. Please be respectful of others. Not much effort was put into this answer, but invalidating anyone's efforts--small or not--is not nice, and people will stop answering your questions after awhile.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for the latter ones. So I'll leave it like it is now! *(I'm fine with it anyway...)*

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Why is $\|Qx\|\leq \|x\|$?